# importing big amount of data from channeladvisor using php

Tags: php, curl

I am importing products from channeladvisor. I am writing in PHP and using curl for import (I was using nusoap before but the problem persisted). I have a customer who has 80000 products.

Does anyone know some effective way to import large amount of products?

This is my flow to import:

- I get 100 `sku`s by `GetFilteredSkuList`.
- Then I go `foreach` over this list and pack 10 curl objects for `multi_curl` and fire them
- I gather the info and loop further more.
- After I finish with the 100 sku I call `GetFilteredSkuList` to get a new 100
- And so on.

For some reason my import stops after about 6880 products. 
it does not give me any error - nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use function `set_time_limit(0)`
2. Use function `ignore_user_abort(true)`. Ignore user aborts and allow the script to run forever
3. Increase memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit','1024')`